# WordPress image uploader does not generate thumbnails after permalink change

Tags: wordpress

I am currently running wordpress 3.0.1 on IIS.

I have just changed my permalink settings to use almost-pretty URLs - /index.php/2010/08/example-post. During this change I added a php.ini file to the website's root directory with the required settings:

cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
cgi.force_redirect = 0

After this change the image uploader no longer generates thumbnails when I upload an image. There is no error message, and the original full size image is successfully uploaded, just the thumbnails are not created. If I remove the php.ini file thumbnail generation works but almost-pretty URLs breaks.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem here is with my php.ini file. Being new to php I simply uploaded a php.ini to my site directory that contained only the 2 settings required by wordpress for almost-pretty-urls, leaving out all other settings:

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
cgi.force_redirect = 0
```

I thought the default php.ini file for the server would be picked up and combined with my custom one, thus only overwriting the settings I needed to and keeping everything else as expected... obviously this is not the case.

Using a php.ini from my hosting provider as the base with my changes has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This link has your answer:

http://coderjournal.com/2008/02/url-rewriter-reverse-proxy-iis-wordpress/

This will allow you to have the pretty url without the change to your ini file.

Comment: Thanks Todd, but I don't think this will work for me for 2 reasons. Firstly, the method is just rewriting the urls to add the "index.php" portion before being handled by wordpress. My urls already have the "index.php" in them with the "prettiness" coming after that. E.g. http://domain.com/index.php/2010/09/sample-post/. In order for that url to work you must have the php.ini changes in place. Secondly, my hosting provider sux and won't install any modifications/extensions to IIS for security reasons.